# How to do process with for() function and give return true in the last

Tags: php

I have a project, and I have one problem. Can you help me? I have this code:

```
for($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++){
   if(do_something == true){
      return true;
   }else{
      return false;
   }
}
```

If, I have 10 data, and I want `do_something` is process all my data. But the problem is, the script is stop in first data. So, I delete the `return true;` and leave it blank. Now the script process all my data. My question is, how can I put `return true;` in the end of the process, so I know no error in the process.

Comment: why all are forgotting count in loop

Comment: @raghavendra nobody is. Counting is done with "$i++" in the first line.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr i mean length of $rows in the loop

Comment: @raghavendra I don't get what you mean; the value is a boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
for($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++){
   if(do_something == false){
       return false;
   }
}
return true;
```

it will "do something" as long as it is successful, and until all are done, and abort at the first "false" result of "do something".

Answer (score 0):

Just change your logic a bit and do something like this:

So if something goes wrong you stop and `return FALSE`, if everything went correct you end the loop and `return TRUE`.

```
for($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
   if(do_something != TRUE)
       return FALSE;
}
return TRUE;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$j=0;
for($i=0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
    if(do_something == true) {
        /*return true;*/
        $j++;    
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
if($j == $rows) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```